# remove white space from web page background

Tags: html, css, angular, web, sass

I'm trying to remove white space from the background of html page and I have used this code but still facing the same problem!

[image: result]

I'm using angular 7 with node 10 and chrome browser

**HTML file...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

**SCSS file...**

```
$colors: (
  primary: #000000,
  fonts: #ffffff
);

body {
  background-color: map-get($colors,primary);
  color: map-get($colors, fonts );
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the element inspector in your browser development tools. It will show you where it comes from.

Comment: and also if I didn't  write the "hello world" the background wont appear at all :/ !

Comment: Have you tried using the browser development tools and inspected?

Comment: I put this in codepen and it worked fine.  I think there something you're not sharing. recommend doing what lurker says and look at the element inspector.  Just right-click on hello world and select inspect.

Comment: I see 8px margin at the body element, even though I have set them to 0px in my scss !

Comment: The inspector will tell you where it's getting that 8px from if you look at the inspector window information.

Comment: Are these really your only files? What links the your HTML to the particular SCSS file you show? Inspect other parts of your main HTML page and make sure they are what you'd expect.

Comment: What you're showing as your result doesn't really align with your code. You are setting the background of the entire body, but your result only shows what appears to be some other container holding "Hello World" with a dark background because it doesn't extend down the whole page.

Comment: problem Solved :D ! It seemed like there is another global file that specifies a default values for elements. I have changed body margin to 0px at the styles.scss file and it works. actually I have mentioned that I'm using angular framework. Anyway, thanksss aloot for INSPECTION advice :DDD

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used angular before so I am not sure if it will work. But I don't think it should make a difference.

What you want to do is a browser reset.

The default is set to content-box which includes a padding and margin from the browser. Using the universal selector, set the padding and margin to zero. Set the box-sizing property to border-box in your body element and then have the universal selectors inherit the box-sizing property.

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting white space because `<body>` tag is taking default margin/padding. So you just need to make it 0 in your CSS.

***css -***

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It should do the job.